# atoi and leading 0's for decimal numbers

Tags: c, decimal, atoi

When using `atoi` in C I am trying to convert a `char` array of numbers to an `int`. I have leading `0`'s on my number though and they are not preserved when I print the number out later.

```
char num[] = "00905607";
int number;

number = atoi(num);

printf("%d", number);
```

The output from this will be `905607` and I would like it to be `00905607`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, no it doesn't; `atoi` converts to decimal regardless of leading zeros. Secondly, you're printing out the original character array, not the converted number.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't convert anything and especially not to octal ..

Comment: And you should probably use `char num[] = ...` rather than a zero length array.

Answer (score 6):

You can do padding on your printf() so if you wanted every output to be 8 characters long you would use

```
printf("%08d", number);
```

Comment: Does not seem to be the right answer because it fixes de size of de number in 8. 

So this code will get you leading zeros to fulfill this request. 

If your code sends a 001 number.. it will become 00000001 instead. 

So strtol with base 10 from @stephen-canon seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use [strtol](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?strtol%283%29) instead. It allows you to specify the base.

Answer (score 4):

That code is working properly, if it works at all. The integer is 905607... leading zeros don't exist in a mathematical sense.

You have a lot of issues with that code. You're declaring your string improperly, and you're not printing the converted number. Also, if you were doing `printf(number);` you'd need to use a format string. If you'd like to have leading spaces in that, you can use a width specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use atoi.  Use strtol with a base of 10.

In general, there's no reason to use atoi in 
modern code.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers assume you want 8 digits while this is not exactly what you requested.

If you want to keep the number of leading zeros, you're probably better keeping it as a string, and convert it with `strtol` for calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you want to display ints you have to format them as strings again. An integer is just a number, it doesn't contain any information on how to display it. Luckily, the printf-function already contains this, so that would be something like

```
printf( "%08d", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sscanf, and provide '%d' as your format string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that behavior; don't use atoi.

Perhaps sscanf with a %d format?

Answer (score 0):

You could also count the numbers of numbers in the string and create a new one with leading zeroes.

Or check out all the wonderful format tags for printf and use one to pad with zeroes.
Here for example are lot of them:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 0):

```
char num[] = "00905607";
int number;

number = atoi(num);
printf("%0*d", (int)strlen(num), number);
```