# Converting string to int without removing zero's

Tags: c, string, int

I have string like

```
char str[10] = "0123456789";
```

I need to convert it into `int`. I tried it with `atoi` but this function removes `0`. I searched it in google and found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694926/atoi-and-leading-0s-for-decimal-numbers). Many answers have provided solution using `strtol` but its not working. Following is the code I am using for `strtol`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char str[30] = "0123456789 This is test";
 char *ptr;
 int ret;

 ret = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
 printf("The number is %d\n", ret);
 printf("String part is %s\n", ptr);

 return(0);
}

 Output:
 The number is 123456789
 String part is This is test
```

What's wrong I am doing in this case. How to convert string to int without removing zero's.

Comment: [Your output is incorrect](https://ideone.com/vvaOxa)-

Comment: Assuming your compiler's `int` type can represent the value `123456789` (which not all can) what value do you expect `atoi("0123456789")` to give, and is that value different from `123456789`?

Comment: I know atoi will remove 0 as it doesn't make any sense. But for some reasons I need to include 0

Comment: You wrote *The number is 0123456789* - This is incorrect despite long/int

Comment: @Andrew in which case you cannot use an int to store it.

Comment: `int` stores a number. `5` and `05` are the same number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format your output accordingly.

- `%d` just prints the int in decimal using the shortest string representation (no leading zeros)
- `%8d` (for example) will print the int in decimal in a field of size 8 (leading spaces if needed)
- `%08d` (for example) will print the int in decimal in a field of size 8 with leading zeros.

Comment: I dont need to print the value. I need to save it in a variable

Comment: A number is a number, it has no leading zero or whatever, its representation with digits can have leading zeros (you can simply imagine that an int is a set of pebbles - so no leading zeros or whatever) ... If you want to represent it back into a string (with leading zeros or not) then use `sprintf`.